# jquery datatables refresh after create/update

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jquery datatables as ... a table ;) 
I have some sort of data into it and I want to edit them. When I click on the "edit" link, dialog (http://fancybox.net/) appears. It contain simple form with 3 inputs. I click on the submit button, then data in db are updated and here is the problem. How can I refresh the datatable and force it to back on the previously selected page? Now I have the code that just refresehes whole parent page. Im not satisfied with that solution.

Best regards

EDIT:
ok I can see that this can be done with "bStateSave": true

Answer (score 1):

bStateSave will do this, but you can also do this by saving the `iDisplayStart` setting prior to the refresh and then applying that setting to the table during redraw.